# weighted maximum likelihood as loss function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, loss-functions

I have built a little neural network that I use for regression.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


def NLL(y, distr): 
  return -distr.log_prob(y) 
 
def normal_exp(params): 
  return tfd.Normal(loc=params[:,0:1], scale=tf.math.exp(params[:,1:2]))# both parameters are learnable  

def modelcov():
    

    inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
    hidden = Dense(200,activation="relu")(inputs)
    hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
    hidden = Dense(200,activation="relu")(hidden)
    hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
    hidden = Dense(200,activation="relu")(hidden)
    hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
    params_mc = Dense(2)(hidden)
    dist_mc = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_exp, name='normal_exp')(params_mc) 

    modello = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dist_mc)
    return modello
```

where the last layer produce a realization from a normal distribution.

The problem is that my dataset (x,y,y_std)  cointains the errors y_std on the measured values of y. Since data with bigger errors contains less information, I was wondering if from the statistical point of view   made sense to set sample_weight= 1/y_std**2  in the compile method so that the neural network would use a weighted maximum likelihood estimator, rather than the simple MLE

```
test = modelcov()
test.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.004), loss=NLL) 
storia = test.fit(x,y,sample_weight=1/y_std**2, epochs=5000,verbose=0,batch_size=128)
```

Is it correct in the Bayesian framework to use the square of the inverse of the uncertainties on the measurements y as weights for the loss function ?

Comment: negative log likelihood of *which probability model*? MSE is the MLE of a certain probability model, so your question doesn't make much sense. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Sycorax sorry i am new to this particular field and sometimes i make errors. i use the usual normal distribution

Comment: Your post would be clearer if you write out the specific functions you are comparing. You can do this with math typesetting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sycorax i added the coding part. it should clarify what i meant

Comment: How do you calculate that `std`?

Comment: @Dave ah it was given in the dataset as the error associated with the measurements